# Control quantity of Bools generated using arc4random

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, arc4random

In my spritekit game, I spawn one of two enemies. The enemy to be spawned is decided on a random generated bool, using `arc4random_uniform(2)`.

I'm trying to create a way of controlling the distribution. Basically, I don't want it to generate 3 `1`'s (`true`'s) in a row...

I figured the best way to do that would be to check each time somethings generated, and increment a count, and if it exceeds the count, change the generated `bool` to the opposite value.

I think I'm confusing myself a little though as I can't get it to work.

Is there a simple way to do this, or can my code be modified to get it working? Thanks.

```
var randomSequenceNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) == 0 ? true: false

    if randomSequenceNumber {
        seqCount = randomSequenceNumber
        obNum++
        print("Obstacle Count: ", obNum)
    }

    if obNum <= 3 {
        randomSequenceNumber = !seqCount
        obNum = 0
    }
```

(probably having a major brain fart)

Comment: Always choosing "false" after two "true"s makes the enemy predictable :)

Comment: True, but sometimes I was getting 6 or 7 in a row. Maybe changing it to 5. It would be nice to still be random, but if the next one was the same as the previous 4, it be changed and the count reset, so worst case scenario, you get 4 false | 4 true | 4 false etc... but it could still be T F T F F T T T F T FF TT F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to generate random `bools` in a sequence, but should the same `bool` value get generated more than 3 times in a row, it was changed to the opposite.

But at the same time, I didn't just want it to just alternate, like `true false true false true false` etc

So it could gerate `true false true false true false`, or `true true false false true false true false false true false` but never `true true true true false true false true false false false false`... etc

This meant I needed to store the values, compare them, change the value if the last `x` amount matched, and reset the stored values ready to compare next time around.

This is how I did it:

```
var randSeqArray: [Bool] = []                          //empty array for bools
```

In my function that generates `bools`:

```
    randSeqArray.append(randomBool)                    //add bool to array
    if randSeqArray.count == 2 {                       //if matches count
        if randSeqArray[0] == randSeqArray[1] {        //if elements match
            print("-------> last two bools matched!")
            randomBool = !randomBool                   //change bool to opposite
        }
        randSeqArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)     //empty array
        randSeqArray.append(randomBool)                //add bool back, ready to check next time
    }
```

Obviously, this code ensures the random bool alternates (for testing), but it can be adopted to allow a possibility of up to `x` matching bools in a row before it gets reset.

This is the above example that checks if the last 3 generated bools match, ensuring that you never get more than 2 of the same bools in a row:

```
    randSeqArray.append(randomBool)
    if randSeqArray.count == 3 {
        if randSeqArray[0] == randSeqArray[1] && randSeqArray[1] == randSeqArray[2] {
            print("-------> last three bools matched!")
            randomBool = !randomBool
        }
        randSeqArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        randSeqArray.append(randomBool)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gameplaykit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GameplayKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015199) introduces some new random number generators including [`GKShuffledDistribution`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKShuffledDistribution_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKShuffledDistribution), which, according to Apple, does exactly what you're after:

> A `GKShuffledDistribution` object produces random numbers that across many samplings are uniformly
>   distributed, but where short sequences of similar values are unlikely

`nextBool()` should give you a new random Boolean value within the characteristics of the distribution.

Hope this helps,

Simon

Comment: I thought this was used to shuffle things that aren't repeated?, so numbers 1 through 10 in a random order? If I used this, I'd have to generate a list of bools before hand when I don't know how many need generating :(

Comment: Nope - it does what you're after. Generates a stream of random numbers where short sequences of similar values are unlikely - I've added a link to the Apple documentation in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look. But I'm thinking with only two values, the probability of it generating T F T F T F T F T is likely, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: The distribution has a `nextBool()` method which generates and returns a new random Boolean value within the characteristics of the distribution, i.e. no sequences of the same Boolean :)

Comment: I don't quite get how nextBool() gives the desired result without some trickery. But do think GKShuffleDistribution could be used for this if a range of the length acceptable (in terms of repeats) was used. Maybe.